# Sending requests in background android

Tags: android, background

What is the best way to send requests sequentially in background? I'm having trouble deciding between an `AsyncTask`, `Service` or `Runnable` due to the complexity of my problem. Basically I have a DB, with pending requests, and I want to create a "background job" that doesn't get killed until he finishes his task. This job needs to check if there're any pending request and if yes, send them first. For this I'm planning to have a background task with a queue that consumes the first element and continues the process on success and aborts the operation on failure. It also needs to be a *singleton* so, if any request arrives while it's still sending pending requests, I can guarantee the sequencial state integrity. Said that what do you guys think is the best android class that will suit my problem? Thanks

Comment: Use Volley to send request. It is the faster and better from other ways.

Comment: reffer this https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinking about using this. It looks like a very nice framework to do what I'm looking for https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue